Drawing random samples from statistical distribution
I'm looking for a list of methods to draw random samples from Pareto distributions.
I already found :

Inverse transform sampling
Rejection sampling
Metropolis–Hastings algorithm
Gibbs Sampling

Are there any other important method I've missed ? Thanks.

Sample $Y\sim Exp(\alpha)$ and let $X=x_0, e^Y$ be your Pareto sample

@Henry, that sounds like an answer.  Can I encourage you to write that in the answer box, so it can be upvoted and the question can be considered answered?  The SE platform discourages writing answers in the comments.  Thank you!

Requested from comments:

Sample $Y\sim \operatorname{Exp}(\alpha)$ and let $X=x_0 e^Y$ be your Pareto sample

and similarly

Sample $Z_1,Z_2$ i.i.d. $\mathcal N(0,1)$ and let $X=x_0 \exp\left(\frac{Z_1^2+Z_2^2}{2\alpha}\right)$ be your Pareto sample

